# Evaluate a measure on $\mathbb N$

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on the subsets of $\mathbb N=\{1, 2, \dots\}$ and $\mu(\{n, n+1,\dots\})=\frac{n}{2^n}$. Find $\int x d\mu(x)$.

$$\begin{split}\int xd\mu(x)&=\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{purple}{n1_{x=n}}d\mu(x)&&\text{the domain is $\mathbb N$}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \mu(\{n\})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{n}{2^n}-\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}\end{split}$$

That's what I came up with, but I don't know if it's the right way to relate integration and measure or even if the first step is right.

Comment: Yeah, looks fine to me. Though the end result can be simplified significantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. You write the function $x : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ as an infinite sum

$$ x = \sum _{n=1}^\infty n  1_{x=n} $$

and the next step you use that infinite sum commutes with integration. This is true: in this case you can use the monotone convergence theorem.

Also,
$$\int  n 1_{x=n} d\mu (x) = n \mu(\{n\})$$
since $1_{x=n}$ is a simple function.

The rest is just direct calculations.